How to make URL font size bigger in Chromium?
I am having the latest Chromium snap running on Ubuntu MATE 22.04.5 LTS. The problem is I can make bigger the window content, but I havent figured out how to make bigger URL font text, which is really small. Some answers on the internet suggest this is left on OS, but Ubuntu MATE does not have a feature, which would make URL font size bigger. So I wonder if there is a way in Chromium settings to do that? For example Microsoft Edge or Opera have a decent size of URL text on my workstation.

Change the system font size: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-font-size.html.en, https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/change-panel-font-size-in-mate-1-20/16418/2,

@DrMoishePippik Which one is the system font size on the second link you have provided?
